# changing the product attributes place to top after sku

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

how can we change the position of only two product attributes not all product attributes . i want to move it from bottom to top after sku or after price please see the screenshots attached . 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Go to Store->Attributes->Product, Open your attributes

Comment: n [Storefront Properties] you have position field, add value in this field for all attribute as you wish

Comment: no such attribute in my attributes

Comment: i have seen some other attributes as well i think from attributes we can not set there exact position .

Comment: i think we need to make change in catalog related layout pages

Comment: yes i was trying this but unable to help myself . i tried this to see if something change . <move element="product.attributes" destination="product.info.stock.sku" after="-"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83702/discussion-between-samair-ali-and-aditya-shah).